# Unit testing of UITableView cell. Access to cell's nib

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, unit-testing, xib

I try to test whether my table view cell gets right values. The cell is customized and has its own xib file.

```
self.organizationController?.organizationsTableView.registerNib(UINib.init(nibName:String(OrganizationTableViewCell), bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: String(OrganizationTableViewCell))
let organizationName = "Name"
let organization = Organization.organizationWithName(organizationName, index: 0)
self.organizationController?.organizations = [organization]
let cell = self.organizationController?.organizationsTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)) as! OrganizationTableViewCell
XCTAssertEqual(cell.organizationNameLabel.text, organizationName, "Cell created properly")
```

With this code I got an error: `Could not cast value of type 'myApplication.OrganizationTableViewCell' to 'myApplicationTests.OrganizationTableViewCell'`

When I change module in xib file to `myApplicationTests` it starts to work properly for test cases but doesn't work for a usual application run. How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You probably solved this months ago but sounds like you just need to either change the nib's target membership to include myApplicationTests or import myApplication at the top of your tests file.